# Weird results when working with timezone conversions in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a java app that needs to work with timezones. At a fixed interval it saves some information to a database with a timestamp. Here's the code that converts it to UTC:

```java
public static ZonedDateTime toUTC(LocalDateTime date, ZoneId zone) {
   ZonedDateTime from = date.atZone(zone);
   return from.withZoneSameInstant(utc);
}
```

This works fine until I try to poll data from the database. I have to create two UTC timestamps to get the info for the day. In my case I'm expecting these stamps to be from 7 AM to 7 AM of the next day, but instead I'm getting 5 PM to 5 PM of the next day. Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: Here's both DB methods, I'm using MariaDB with timestamps.

````java
public void saveTally(int tally) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime utc = TimeUtil.toUTC(now, system);
        Timestamp stamp = Timestamp.valueOf(TimeUtil.formatter.format(utc));

        try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            DSLContext context = DSL.using(connect, SQLDialect.MARIADB);

            context.insertInto(STATISTICS, STATISTICS.DATE, STATISTICS.ONLINEUSERS)
                    .values(stamp, tally)
                    .execute();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("JDBC experienced the following error:" + ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e) + " Please see below for details");
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    public DataSet getStatistics(String date, String timezone) {
        LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date + " 00:00:00", parser);

        Timestamp min = Timestamp.valueOf(TimeUtil.formatter.format(TimeUtil.toUTC(localDate, ZoneId.of(timezone))));
        Timestamp max = Timestamp.valueOf(TimeUtil.formatter.format(TimeUtil.toUTC(localDate.plusDays(1), ZoneId.of(timezone))));
        try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            DSLContext context = DSL.using(connect, SQLDialect.MARIADB);

            Result<Record> result = context.select()
                    .from(STATISTICS)
                    .where(STATISTICS.DATE.greaterOrEqual(min))
                    .and(STATISTICS.DATE.lessThan(max))
                .fetch();

            return new DataSet(result.intoResultSet());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("JDBC experienced the following error:" + ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e) + " Please see below for details");
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e));
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }

        return null;
    }```
````

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls this method?

Comment: What database are you using? How did you declare the type of the database column? Few databases support a timestamp with zone type, but most support a UTC timestamp type, and a local time type. So can you explain why you are using `ZonedDateTime` instead of `Instant`, if you want a Unix time stamp?

Comment: I made some edits to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. It turns out that I was using GMT based ID's (GMT-7 for MST etc.) and they were inaccurate. Mystery solved!

Comment: Also your handling of time types is unnecessarily complicated. Want a `java.sql.Timestamp` for "now"? `Timestamp.from(Instant.now(clock))` Converting a `ZonedDateTime` to a `Timestamp`? `Timestamp.from(zoned.toInstant())`

Answer (score 0):

Saving to DB might be the problem here. How exactly is it done?
An instance of `ZonedDateTime` returned by the method contains 2 fields: a number of seconds (timestamp) and info about timezone. During the travel of that object to a DB, info about timezone could be lost.

Comment: There is no timezone stored in the DB. The date is stored as just a timestamp. The issue comes in when I'm trying to create new timestamps for use in querying the db